# Login to MineCraft using C#

Tags: c#, authentication, minecraft, launcher

I'm trying to create a simple custom minecraft launcher for myself and some friends. I don't need the code to start minecraft, just the actual line of code to login. For example, to my knowledge, you used to be able to use:

```
    string netResponse = httpGET("https://login.minecraft.net/session?name=<USERNAME>&session=<SESSION ID>" + username + "&password=" + password + "&version=" + clientVer);
```

I'm aware there is no longer a https://login.minecraft.net, meaning this code won't work. This is about all I need to continue, only the place to connect to login, and the variables to include. Thanks, if any additional info is needed, give a comment.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make a JSON POST request to https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate and heres my method of getting an access token (which you can use to play the game)

Code:

```
string ACCESS_TOKEN;
public string GetAccessToken()
{
    return ACCESS_TOKEN;
}
public void ObtainAccessToken(string username, string password)
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = "{\"agent\":{\"name\":\"Minecraft\",\"version\":1},\"username\":\""+username+"\",\"password\":\""+password+"\",\"clientToken\":\"6c9d237d-8fbf-44ef-b46b-0b8a854bf391\"}";

        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            ACCESS_TOKEN = result;
        }
    }
}
```

Declare these aswell:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

And if you haven't already, refrence System.Web.Extentions
I tested this with C# winforms and it works :)

Thanks,

DMP9

Answer (score 1):

The login server is now `https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate`, and it uses JSON-formatted info.

Use this format for the JSON request:

```json
{"agent": { "name": "Minecraft", "version": 1 }, "username": "example", "password": "hunter2"}
```

[Here](https://github.com/ORelio/Minecraft-Console-Client/blob/8eb71bd3f8e0a9531cec75248b72820c1233df3f/MinecraftClient/Protocol/ProtocolHandler.cs#L131) is a full implementation for logging in.

Comment: I see, and where would I find the Reference for
        using MinecraftClient.Protocol.Handlers;
        using MinecraftClient.Proxy;
?

Comment: @Xceptionist The rest of that code can be found [here](https://github.com/ORelio/Minecraft-Console-Client).