# Authenticate Minecraft with C#

Tags: c#, authentication, minecraft

I am trying to figure out how to log into Minecraft from C#.
I found [Login to MineCraft using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331163/login-to-minecraft-using-c-sharp) - So I used the code from DMP9 MC, but it didn't work.
Is there any other way?
I am attempting to make my own launcher.
Here is my code:

```
string ACCESS_TOKEN;
    public string GetAccessToken()
    {
        return ACCESS_TOKEN;
    }
    public void ObtainAccessToken(string username, string password)
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"agent\":{\"name\":\"Minecraft\",\"version\":1},\"username\":\"" + username + "\",\"password\":\"" + password + "\",\"clientToken\":\"6c9d237d-8fbf-44ef-b46b-0b8a854bf391\"}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                ACCESS_TOKEN = result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Somewhere else in the code:

```
private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ObtainAccessToken("My Email", "My Password");
        string code = GetAccessToken();
        string strCmdText;
        strCmdText = "java -Xms512m -Xmx1g -Djava.library.path=natives/ -cp \"minecraft.jar; lwjgl.jar; lwjgl_util.jar\" net.minecraft.client.Minecraft " + "My Email" + " " + code;
        Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 (Personal) and running Windows 7.
Thanks,
Flo :3

*Where I wrote 'My Email' or 'My Password', I had that as my login details, I just didn't want it on a public website.*

Comment: you say "it didn't work", what did not work exactly? do you have an exception or something?

Comment: @Tewr Oh! Turns out it wasn't that code that wasn't working. My code that was supposed to launch Minecraft was the code that was making the error! I just removed the launching Minecraft code, and just set some text to the output, and it works fine. I was trying to use the output as the access token, when I should have been getting the access token from the json. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! Turns out my code to launch the game was what wasn't working. I thought it would give me the access token, so I set some text to the output, and I realized that the output was JSON that had the access code inside of it. Thanks!