# Minecraft authentication servers returning 403 forbidden

Tags: c#, post, minecraft

So, I'm trying to create a new authToken by sending a POST Request via C# to the minecraft authentication servers (https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate), but im getting the following error:

```
System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'
```

My current code to try and send the request is:

```
                public void ObtainAccessToken(string username, string password)
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://authserver.mojang.com/authenticate");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"agent\":{\"name\":\"Minecraft\",\"version\":1},\"username\":\"" + username + "\",\"password\":\"" + password + "\"}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                
            }
        }
    }
```

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28591279/17371073

I'm trying to log into an migrated account

Comment: The way to login have changed 2 times since the mentionned post

Comment: ok how do i do it then

Comment: See here: https://wiki.vg/Authentication

Comment: i did wdym the code should work with whats on the wiki

Answer (score 0):

Using my Java implementation from a few years back as a reference, the only difference I see is that I've added `Content-Charset` `UTF-8` and `Content-Length` with the written payload byte size to the request header (that is, the byte size of the json string that you write). I suspect that I would have never done this if this wasn't necessary.

Edit: Following [HTTP specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/draft-ietf-http-spec.html#BodyLength), your request is only valid if you either:

- Include the `Content-Length` property in your HTTP header.
- Close the connection directly after sending the HTTP request.

Since you are waiting for a response, you'll have to use the first option.